# Filescoped namespaces in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to use filescoped namespaces in visual studio 2019. So instead of:-

```
namespace my.namespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

I want:-

```
namespace my.namespace;

public class MyClass
{
}
```

Following online tutorials and going through other answers I have tried adding `editorConfig` file but the editorConfig visual studio is generating for me is different than what I am seeing online. My file is starting with this text:-

```
# Rules in this file were initially inferred by Visual Studio IntelliCode from the C:\myproject codebase based on best match to current usage at 3/25/2022
# You can modify the rules from these initially generated values to suit your own policies
# You can learn more about editorconfig here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference
[*.cs]


#Core editorconfig formatting - indentation

#use soft tabs (spaces) for indentation
indent_style = space

#Formatting - indentation options

#indent switch case contents.
csharp_indent_case_contents = true
#indent switch labels
csharp_indent_switch_labels = true
```

And this file has no information on filescoped namespaces.

Comment: i think that's one of the latest C# versions features, so you prob. have to upgrade to VS 2022

Comment: @PatrickBeynio Not an option for me at the moment, my environment is inside a virtual machine which is running out of space. I cant install VS22 on that box right now.

Comment: well than, without V2022 or a preview version, which wouldn't be meant for production anyway, you're out of luck i guess